# Question on Fourier Series Equivalency

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x04dnqg-iPw&ab_channel=AlphaTutoring) says that the formula for a Fourier Series is

$$f(x)≈a_0+\sum_{n=1}^N\left[a_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\right]$$

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) says that the formula is

$$s_N(x)≈\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^N
\left[a_n\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{P}nx\right)+b_n\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{P}nx\right)\right]$$

My question is: Are these two equations equivalent? If so, how can we write $L$ in terms of $P$ and $n$? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: Please don't close this question for vagueness; not all math problems involve a mathematical calculation.

Comment: You don't need to write $L$ in terms of $P$. They are merely symbols, and can be used interchangeably; if you like you can use your own favorite symbol. Instead of $L$ or $P$, write $M$, for example. These symbols determine the period of the functions involved. So, yes -- the two equations are equivalent.

Comment: But then why is the first term in the second one a/2?

Comment: The difference in the $a_0$ coefficient comes from the way in which it is defined. In the video, the integral defining $a_0$ is divided by $2L$. In wikipedia, it is divided by $L$. The two definitions are therefore still equivalent, provided we know exactly how the coefficients are defined.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, the use of different symbols $L$ and $P$ for the period and the relative factor of $2$ between the two definitions of $a_0$ doesn’t make the representations inequivalent.